# perl: assign list returned by func as a ref in a hashmap value

Tags: perl

What I am trying to do is assign the list returned to me by glob to a value in a hashmap. I am aware value is scalar and therefore it must be assigned as a reference. For example this would work:

```
my @stuff = glob("foo");
my %hashmap =
(
  "stuff" => \@stuff
);
```

However I want to do it all at once. Is that possible? This doesn't work:

```
my %hashmap =
(
  "stuff" => \@{glob("foo")}
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating an array reference to hash values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372443/creating-an-array-reference-to-hash-values)

Comment: Another possible dup target: [How do I return a list as an array reference in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065579/how-do-i-return-a-list-as-an-array-reference-in-perl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the construction

```
my %hashmap =
(
  "stuff" => [ glob("foo") ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for!